# How to implement resizable rectangle in PySide6 QGraphicsView

Tags: python, qt, qgraphicsview, pyside6

I am trying unsucessfully to implement a resizable rectangle QGraphicsItem in the pyside6 QGraphics framework by inheriting from `QGraphicsRectItem`. In the `ResizableRectItem` class, I create resize handles that are themselves `QGraphicsRectItems` and children of the `ResizableRectItem`, which allows them to be translated together with their parent item.

The problem I encounter and can't seem to solve, is that I want these handles to only appear when the Rectangle is selected with the mouse. This works fine (by overriding the `itemChange` method), but the problem is that the handles can only be moved when the Rectangle is NOT selected. While the rectangle is selected, they cannot be moved.

Moreover, I don't know how, once I get the handles to move, I can propagate the movement of a specific handle to the parent rectangle, so as to resize its shape accordingly. I initially thought about using signals/slots, however this mechanism is unavailable since `QGraphicsItem` does not inherit from `QObject`. I read that there is also a `QGraphicsObject` to provide signals/slots, but I suspect there might be a more elegant solution which I'm not seeing at the moment. I would be glad if someone could help me out here. I have googled this question extensively and not found a satisfactory answer. Thank you in advance!

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtGui import QPen, QColor, QBrush
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsRectItem, QGraphicsItem


class ResizableRectItem(QGraphicsRectItem):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setPen(QPen(Qt.black))
        self.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.gray))
        self.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)

        self.handleSize = 8
        self.handles = {}
        self.directions = ['topLeft', 'topRight', 'bottomLeft', 'bottomRight']
        self.createHandles()

    def createHandles(self):
        rect = self.rect()
        pen = QPen(QColor(0, 0, 0))
        for direction in self.directions:
            handle = QGraphicsRectItem(-self.handleSize/2, -self.handleSize/2, self.handleSize, self.handleSize, self)
            handle.setPen(pen)
            handle.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
            handle.setVisible(False)
            # Use getattr to replace this calls like this: rect.upperLeft()
            handle.setPos(getattr(rect, direction)())
            self.handles[direction] = handle

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        # Intercept selection event to change visibility of handles
        if change == QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemChange.ItemSelectedChange:
            for handle in self.handles.values():
                handle.setVisible(bool(value))
        # Pass to original method to handle all other changes
        return super().itemChange(change, value)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setGeometry(500, 500, 500, 500)
        self.view = QGraphicsView()
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)
        rectItem = ResizableRectItem(100, 100, 200, 200)
        self.scene.addItem(rectItem)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Within your question relies an important aspect. QGraphicsItem can show contents that is not actually shown at their *position*. The default position of an item is always at `0, 0` (related to its parent, and based on the [Graphics View Coordinate System](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html#the-graphics-view-coordinate-system)), meaning that if you create a `QGraphicsRectItem(100, 100, 200, 200)` its position will be `0, 0` and its rectangle will be shown at `100, 100`. What do you expect from moving the left/top/right handles? Should they change the item's position or just its rect?

Comment: The handles should change also the position, since the center of the Item will inevitably move when resizing. The resizing should be just as in a powerpoint shape.

Comment: Focus on a single problem. Anyway, for the first problem related on selected items, you can return ```False``` in the ```itemChange()``` if the ```value``` is ```True```. And for the second problem, you can use the ```mouseXxxEvent()``` methods of the ```QGraphicsItem```.

Comment: What would be accomplished by returning `False` in the `itemChange` method?

Comment: @sunnytown I'm afraid you've not understood the point. It's obvious that resizing the rectangle will move its center, but, as said, you can have a rectangle *shown* at certain coordinates while having its item *placed* at others: doing `ResizableRectItem(100, 100, 200, 200)` gives you a rectangle *shown* at (100,100), but the item is placed at (0,0); you can also do `ResizableRectItem(0, 0, 200, 200)` and then `rectItem.setPos(100, 100)`, then you will have a similar *visual* result, but it will **not** be the same thing, and there is a *huge* difference between those ways of item placement.

Comment: @relent95 Returning `False` for `ItemSelectedChange` is not a solution, as it will prevent the selection to be applied (thus making the item *not* selected both programmatically *and* visually); besides, "returning `False` if the `value` is `True`" is fundamentally the same thing as *always* returning `False`: since the value for that `GraphicsItemChange` is a boolean, it would be as pointless as doing `return False if value else False`, which is exactly the same as doing `return False`.

Comment: @sunnytown I may have a possible answer for you, but you really need to clarify the aspect of top and left coordinates (whether they are item or contents based, because that aspect can change a lot of things). I strongly suggest you to read more about the [Graphics View Coordinate System](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/graphicsview.html#the-graphics-view-coordinate-system) and how the coordinates of each item (and their contents) are related to their parent(s), including the scene and the view.

Comment: @musicamante, I suggested a partial solution of deselecting the selected item after showing markers(handles), which enables to move the markers. You are right for just returning ```False```.